# Hide Accound Dashboard Link depending upon customer group

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I have added two links to customer dashboard "Proposals" and "Documentaion". I have also added a customer group "xyz". I want to only show the mentioned group.  Similarly, I want to hide these two links for other groups.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest below reference code. There are two ways to do this

1. Create a new layout that will work filter based on the customer group. Forex customer_group_general.xml. In this file, you can hide/remove the left navigation link which you have added using the XML file. Please follow the steps to create a new layout:

- Create a new module
- Add di.xml file in the etc/frontend folder

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
>     <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page">
>         <plugin name="[pluginName]" type="[Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\[ClassName]" sortOrder="10"/>
>     </type>
> </config>
> ```

- Create plugin php file in your module in app/code/[codePool]/[Vendor]/[ModuleName]/Plugin/[ClassName].php

> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace [Vendor]\[ModuleName]\Plugin;
>
> use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
> use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
> use Magento\Store\Model\GroupFactory;
>
> class [ClassName]
> {
>     protected $customerSession;
>
>     protected $groupFactory;
>
>     public function __construct(
>         Session $customerSession,
>         GroupFactory $groupFactory
>     ) {
>         $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
>         $this->groupFactory = $groupFactory;
>     }
>
>     public function afterAddPageLayoutHandles(Page $subject)
>     {
>         $group = $this->groupFactory->create()
>             ->load($this->customerSession->getCustomerGroupId());
>         if ($group->getId() >= 0) {
>             $handle = sprintf("customer_group_%s", strtolower(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", '_', $group->getName())));
>             $subject->addHandle($handle);
>         }
>
>         return $subject;
>     }
> }
> ```

Now you can create a customer_group_default.xml and update the link based on your requirement. Please review the reference link for more details.

https://www.smartiehastheanswer.co.uk/magento2/adding-custom-dynamic-layout-handles-globally-in-magento2.html

2. Create a custom link that will come from the phtml file. In phtml file, you can add your conditions and it will update in the left navigation.

> ```
> <block class="Custom\Sales\Block\Link" name="downloads-new" template="Custom_Sales::link.phtml">
>     <arguments>
>         <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">210</argument>
>     </arguments>
> </block>
> ```

link.phtml

> ```
> <?php if($block->hidelink()):?>
> <li class="custom link" > 
> <a href="<?= /* @noEscape */
> $block->getUrl('test/index/index')?>" class="custom-link">
>    <?php echo __("My Link")?>
> </a> 
> </li>
> <?php }?>
> ```

Link.php

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Custom\Sales\Block;
>
> use Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface;
>
> /**
>  * Class Link
>  *
>  * @api
>  * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.DepthOfInheritance)
>  * @since 100.0.2
>  */
> class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link implements SortLinkInterface
> {
>     /**
>      * {@inheritdoc}
>      * @since 101.0.0
>      */
>     public function getSortOrder()
>     {
>         return $this->getData(self::SORT_ORDER);
>     }
>
>     public function hideLink() {
>         //Add condition
>         return false;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

In block, you can load current logged in customer and sent true or false flag in the link.phtml

I hope this will help you.

Thanks. If you need any help, please let me know.

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: This will only hide custom links what I want to achive is that when the particular customer belongs to group it will display only custom  links other wise it will hide it.

Comment: It means you also want to hide the Magento default customer links as well when particular customer login from a specific group, is it?

Comment: Yes I want to  hide default links as well

Comment: then you have to create a module as I have mentioned in the above comment and create a catalog_group_groupname.xml file and hide links from the XML file. Else you can add css (display:none) for particular links based on the current customer login and call that phtml file on all the customer_account pages(I would not prefer this solution).

Comment: I have create links using xml. Will creating catalog_group_groupname.xml work to remove other things